# Android Linking between 2 WebView Fragments

Tags: android, html, android-intent, fragment, href

does someone know how I can link between 2 WebView fragments?
Both WebView fragments use local html sources. So I want to link to the other
WebView Fragment via inline HTML href.

[image]

I think something like Intent or Fragment Interfaces could work here. But don´t know exactly how to access the href tag to native Android code.

If you see the picture above - the solution should be open Link WebView 1 and switch to the 2nd WebView. Its implemented with Bottom Navigation, so the first Tab (WebView) should switch over the second Tab (WebView) as it works nativly on tabbing the icons.

**UPDATE**

This new material design in Android is amazing. 
When i want to programatically switch the view - I don´t have to call the fragment transaction methods. I just have to do this:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
            navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

**and now the magic:**

```
navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_myView);
```

This also sync the Bottom Navigation State and load the fragment view.
In my case i call this within a JavaScript Bridge.
Android rocks friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the `JavascriptInterface` annotation class. The `JavascriptInterface` annocation gives you a way to call Android methods from javascript in your `WebView`.

You can find a ton of tutorials out there, but the way it works basically is this:

- Create a POJO with a method you would like to call from javascript in your `WebView`.  This method can have only `String` type arguments.
- Annotate the method with @JavascriptInterface annotation.
- Call `webView.addJavaScriptInterface(pojo, "js")` to inject your POJO into the `WebView`.  (The String tag is arbitrary.)
- In your javascript, call `js.yourMethod()` to invoke the method on your POJO.

So in your case, when someone clicks the button in webview1, you call an Android method through the javascript interface to display webview2.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I thought something about a JavaScript Bridge. I check this stuff out.

Comment: I found an awesome way to switch the View check my UPDATE above